# html5 canvas drawing partially

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[image: This is what I want to create]

I want to create the logo above using the html5 canvas but at the end of the day, it displayed only a triangle. 
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Coa</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="logo" width="900" height="80">
            <h1>COA</h1>
        </canvas>

        <script>
        //function that draw the logo. I create a JavaScript function for drawing the
        var drawLogo = function(){
            var canvas = document.getElementById('logo');
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            //applying gradient
            var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 40);
            gradient.addColorStop(0, "#aa0000");
            gradient.addColorStop(1, "#ff0000");

           // use the strokepath,beginPath() and closePath() methods to start drawing a line, stroke and close when finish
            context.fillStyle = gradient;
            context.strokeStyle = gradient;

            context.lineWidth = 2;
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(0, 40);
            context.lineTo(30, 0);
            context.lineTo(60, 40);
            context.lineTo(285, 40);

            context.fill();
            context.closePath();

            //adding text
            context.font = "italic 40px 'Arial'";
            context.fillText("Coa", 60,36);

            //Moving the Origin so as to fit the square under the triangle 
            context.save();
            context.translate(20, 20);
            context.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);

            //use a path to draw the inner triangle
            context.fillStyle("#ffffff");
            context.strokeStyle("#ffffff");

            context.lineWidth = 2;
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo();
            context.lineTo(0, 20);
            context.lineTo(10, 0);
            context.lineTo(20, 20);
            context.lineTo(0, 20);

            context.fill();
            context.closePath();
            context.restore();
        };

       //Then invoke this method after first checking for the existence of the <canvas> element
        var canvas = document.getElementById("logo");

        if(canvas.getContext){
            drawLogo();
        }

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what am doing wrong that makes the the code not working properly.
I have searched the internet and couldn't find anything tangible that solve the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Try this:

```
if (document.getElementById('logo')) {
var canvas = document.getElementById("logo");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
//applying gradient
var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 40);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "#aa0000");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "#ff0000");
context.strokeStyle = gradient;
context.fillStyle = gradient;
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, 40);
context.lineTo(30, 0);
context.lineTo(60, 40);
context.lineTo(285, 40);
context.stroke();
context.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 20);
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(30, 20);
context.lineTo(37, 28);
context.lineTo(35, 40);
context.lineTo(25, 40);
context.lineTo(23, 28);
context.lineTo(30, 20);
context.fillStyle="#ffffff";
context.fill();
context.fillStyle="#000000";
context.font = "italic 40px Arial";
context.fillText("coa", 60,36);
}
```

I moved around some of your code and it works now for me on Firefox. It looks like you haven't put the pentagon in the canvas yet. Here is a JSFillde:
https://jsfiddle.net/o289buyk/

```
if (document.getElementById('logo')) {
var canvas = document.getElementById("logo");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
//applying gradient
var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 40);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "#aa0000");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "#ff0000");
// use the strokepath,beginPath() and closePath() methods to start drawing a line, stroke and close when finish
context.fillStyle = gradient;
context.strokeStyle = gradient;
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, 40);
context.lineTo(30, 0);
context.lineTo(60, 40);
context.lineTo(285, 40);
context.fill();
context.closePath();
//adding text
context.font = "italic 40px 'Arial'";
context.fillText("Coa", 60,36);
//Moving the Origin so as to fit the square under the triangle
context.save();
context.translate(20, 20);
context.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
//use a path to draw the inner triangle
context.fillStyle("#ffffff");
context.strokeStyle("#ffffff");
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo();
context.lineTo(0, 20);
context.lineTo(10, 0);
context.lineTo(20, 20);
context.lineTo(0, 20);
context.fill();
context.closePath();
context.restore();
}
```

Comment: it only showing partially on Chrome(which am using for testing)

Comment: It works for me. Maybe I am misunderstanding your original question. Are you trying to get what you had coded to be drawn (i.e. could not get the canvas to work), or are you looking to have the actual graphic you posted drawn (i.e. need help with the drawing functions)?

Comment: Are you trying to get what you had coded to be drawn? Yes. Maybe I should add the image of how it displayed on my browser